# Using "what or that" after quantifiers

Tags: quantifiers

Did you really understand all (what / that ) he said?

what is the correct answer "what or that"? Why?

Comment: duplicate [all-that-vs-all-what](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54566/all-that-vs-all-what)

Answer (score 1):

It can be either, but only if "what" is preceded by "of".

> Did you really understand all **that** he said?
>
> Did you really understand all **of what** he said?

are both correct.